# Met Strange situation In Exporting&Running Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have got a strange situation when I working on my project.I have just run my application once. Then I changed some `"android:margin"` properties for my XML files. Then the problem came. I ran the project and it crashed. The log says it comes Resource Not Found Exception. Next I tried to export it but it failed to export. I'll post the log and error dialog below.

What have I done:
I reinstalled everything such as eclipse,ADT and SDK. Not work at all. I'm absolutely sure that the resource exists and stays in right position.**

All useful information is needed.

ps: The resource file that not found is an activity layout xml file--my intro activity and I've found the resource id in my R file.

ps: My friends use the same code as me.They don't have any problem.

here's my layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fl_base_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_base_wallpaper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@color/trans_cc" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: show you xml, the key to solving this problem probably exists in XML file

Comment: Nothing interesting,just a simple layout,no errors for here.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-building your project , If that doesn't work , delete the 'build' and 'gen' folders of project(you can take a backup elsewhere but remove them from your project folder) and then try running it again.

Let me know if that works.....

Comment: I've tried this many times,it doesn't work.I've no idea for this.

Comment: @notal Can't help you unless I can view the xml code.

Comment: I've post it just moment.

Comment: What was the android:margin change you mentioned? I think the error is due to something else and not due to android margin change.

Comment: I've delete that android:layout_magin tag,no use.It crashed again.

Comment: Please post Android manifest and activity.java code. maybe that can tell something about error

Comment: The log says that activity's setContentView() method causes the ResourceNotFound Exception. I just put R.layout.XXXXX in it.This Activity didn't declare in my manifest.xml because I won't use it straightly.I'm sure this xml is in res/layout folder.

Comment: There you go , you need to declare all activities in manifest.

Comment: But I didn't use that straightly.It's just a base class,all my other activities are extends it.And also,my friend uses the same code I copied to him,him didn't got this problem.So I don't think this is a code-occured problem.

Comment: just try adding it to manifest and see if it resolves the error

Comment: Whats the text you've covered in the second image

Comment: I didn't cover anything in it.ImageView just like a wallpaper.I say it again:my friend can run it normally.So I don't think it's a code problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found why : So stupid fail that there is a **resource with no suffix** has been add in my project from SVN. It has a same name with correct resource name but without .png, eclipse can't distinguish what's the difference between them. It has no error notice. WTF!